# If $A$ and $B$ are $n$ by $n$ matrices, show that $\operatorname{Null}A =\operatorname{Null}B$ if and only if $A= UB$ for some invertible $U$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, solution-verification

I know that this has been proven before on this forum, but I need help formalizing a different approach: $\DeclareMathOperator{\Null}{Null}$

$[\leftarrow]$ If $A = UB$ then $\Null(A)=\Null(B)$. Let $x \in \Null(A)$ then
The previous statement is justified since $U$ is invertible hence $x\in \Null(B)$ and $\Null(A) \subseteq \Null(B)$. Make a similar argument for $y \in \Null(B)$, and we can conclude that $\Null(A) = \Null(B)$

$[\rightarrow]$ **This direction I am not so sure** If $\Null(A) = \Null(B)$ and $\operatorname{rank}A=\operatorname{rank}B$ (from the fact they are $n×n$ matrices), then the RREF of the two matrices must be the same. There is a $E_1A=R = E_2B \rightarrow A=E_1^{-1}E_2B\;$ QED

Can someone help confirm or edit the issues in this approach?

Answer (score 1):

If I were your teacher I would prefer to see more detail.  Instead of just saying "since U is invertible hence x∈Null(B) and Null(A)⊆Null(B)" say "suppose $x\in Null(B)$ then Bx= 0 so Ax= UBx= U0= 0 and $x\in Null(A)$.  If $x\in Null(A)$ then Ax= 0 so $Bx= U^{-1}Ax= U^{-1}0= 0$ and $x\in Null(B)$."

Comment: Are both directions correct in process though?

Comment: In order words  in order for the right to be ok ...if rankA=rankB and A and B are both n by n does that mean they have the same RREF ...?